# DateFormat issue in android moto G (3rd Generation) , sign in date

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat df_half = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Log.d(TAG, "" + df_half.format(new Date()));
```

Output ->  HomeFragment: 2,019-12-16

from where this , sign came? only in moto g3. other device working fine

Comment: It should not create issue in moto g3, but what is the language selected of the mobile phone?

Comment: Fwiw I've had trouble with date formatting on specifically Moto G3 devices before: https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/issues/50#issuecomment-245142920

Comment: Language - English (India)        Date&Time - Auto,     TimeZone Auto ,    automatically set GMT +5:30 IST ..  code working ok in other devices

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toString()` today yields `2019-12-17`. On your Moto too, I bet.